# Datastax 4.6 Java driver Object mapper async/batch query

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Datastax java driver 4.6 version I dont see support in object mapper for Batch/async queries

Is there any workaround for it? Any reason why objectmapper has no batch/async support?

Previous version there was MappingManager using which batch and async queries were suppported

Answer (score 2):

Everything is regulated by return type of declared function:

- For async versions, look for documentation for specific annotation, for example, [@Insert](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/mapper/daos/insert/), or [@Select](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/mapper/daos/select/), etc..  But in all cases it's regulated by the return type of the declared function.  To get async version you need to declare function with `CompletionStage<SomeClass>` or `CompletableFuture<SomeClass>` return type
- Batching is similar - you declare function with `BoundStatement` return type, and put that bound statement into batch that is executed via `session.execute`, or `session.executeAsync`.

Comment: Is there any sample code/blog/example i can refer to ? I am assuming batch and async can be done with object mapper. One in documentation were not that clear to me at first go

Comment: I don’t have ready to use examples... ma6be look to GitHub.com/Datastax-Examples? As I wrote, async is easy to do - just adjust function return type in interface declaration...

Comment: Thanks.. Async I got .. Batch let me check especially how to do with objectmapper.

Comment: IIRC, in previous version it was the same - you get bound statement, out it into batch statement, and execute

Comment: Oh thats way I need to write Prepared statement...I was hoping for version of save where i can pass list of entity

Comment: No. You just need to declare version of Insert or Update in the DAO, with BoundStatement as return type, and put a result of that’s call into batch.add. Just wrap it into a loop over your list

Comment: I see let me try that one.. 1 last question . If I have done Mapped UDT which is POJO is there easy function to get UdtValue from it to build UpdateStart based normal CQL update

Comment: Thanks batch statement stuff also worked.. Really helped me.. :-) If there is a way of converting POJO fields to normal cql update using some utility for UDT it would help let me know if you know any

Comment: I’m not sure that I understand your question. Maybe GetEnity can help? https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/mapper/daos/getentity/

Comment: No issues.. Is there a way to ignore field in Pojo from being mapped to DB. Most frameworks marking fields as @transient helps. but didnt work here. Basically POJO as domain level field which i want to be ignored by mapper

Comment: It should be @Transient: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/mapper/entities/